# Is there a library to handle downloadable in-app purchases?

Tags: iphone, ios, download, in-app-purchase

Our app will have downloadable in-app purchases (files hosted with Apple).

The downloader must resume where it got interrupted and continue to work when the app is in

the background. Also users must be able to restore purchases.

I've heard of MKStoreKit and MKNetworkKit. Are these the de-facto standard to implement

downloadable in-app purchases on iOS? Or is there a framework / library that further

simplifies the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guy that created AFNetworking (Matt Thompson) also has a library called [CargoBay](https://github.com/mattt/CargoBay). I didn't notice it when I started on my project, but I'm not sure it would have saved me much based on the complexity of what I needed for in-app purchase. You might also check out [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa), which is what I used to coordinate the events for our store. I use ReactiveCocoa with AFNetworking and find it to be a powerful combination.